# Kendo UI Upload, how to get the path url after uploading file(s) succesful

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a question.
I use Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC to creat upload feature for my web application. It works well, but the problem is user can't see which file(s) they uploaded before after click Upload button to execute submit form, and navigated to other page. In this case, I put a uploader in Create View, and i want after uploading file(s) to server, i will store the link to that file to a field of my model in db, but it always get null value. Can anybody here give me some suggestion to do it. Thank you so much. Here is the code i use.
* Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
   model.Url = Url;
   Db.Models.Add(model);
   Db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments"
            foreach (var file in attachments)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Contents/files/"), fileName);

                DestinationPath = destinationPath;

                file.SaveAs(destinationPath);
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {



  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">
            Upload file
        </div>
        <div style="width:45%">
            @Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("attachments").Async(async => async.Save("Save", "Model").AutoUpload(true)).Multiple(false)
        </div>
    <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="k-button" />
        </p>
```

**Model**

```
public string Url {get;set;}
```

Comment: not sure I understand your problem. Let me paraphrase: On the Create View, you have an Async Kendo Upload.  The user uses this to upload a file.  Then clicks save on the View to submit the form.  But the saved model does not have a link to the uploaded file.  Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, i don't know where to get the link to the file to save to Url.

Answer (score 6):

Client side code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("uploadTagImage")
        .Multiple(false)
        .Async(async => async.Save("ApiUploadImage", "Tag").SaveField("files").AutoUpload(true))
        .Events(events =>
                    {
                        events.Success("PV_Upload_TagImage_OnSuccess");
                    })
)  

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Events
    PV_Upload_TagImage_OnSuccess = function (result) {
        var data = result.response.Data;

        if(data.length > 0) {
            $("#tag-image").attr('src', data[0]);
        }

        $.publish("PV_Grid_Access_OnAddNewRecord_Event");
    };
</script>
```

Server side code:

```
public ActionResult ApiUploadImage([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    var savedFilePaths = new List<string>();
    var applicationPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Content/Images/Others/";
    if(files != null)
    {
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                    
            if(fileName !=null)
            {
                fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmm-") + fileName;
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Others/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(imagePath);
                savedFilePaths.Add(applicationPath + fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(new[] {savedFilePaths}.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct answer. It should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to return an empty string. You can return any string value that you want.

In order to do this, you need to set the response content type to "text/plain".

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```